# Is it possible to except an element from the 'overflow: hidden' property?

Tags: html, css

In my html I am creating a tooltip within an element which should not be invisible outside of the element. It's parent has the `overflow: hidden` property which I want to ignore for this one tooltip element. Is this possible?

> HTML Example

```
<div class="element">
 <p>
  This element is not allowed to overflow
 </p>
 <p class="exception">
   Exceptional overflowing element
 </p>
 <p>
   This element is not allowed to overflow
 </p>
</div>
```

> CSS Example

```
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}

p {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);    
}

.hide-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.exceptional {
// Is there a property to except this element from being invisible?
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zk7qxkjt/2/

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: the only way is to use the position fixed with null transform hack .... https://jsfiddle.net/zk7qxkjt/10/

Comment: if you have option of `append` the tooltip to `body`, than it may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

All I can see is to do something tricky like this :

```
.exception {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
```

But I do not think it is good practise to do something like this, maybe you should re-think your HTML structure ?